# Can anyone tell me what frame this is please?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can anyone tell me what frame I have here? It has RockShox forks and removable rear dropouts.

[image: non-drive side view of rear triangle, which appears to be made of square tubing]
[image: close-up front view of bare head tube]
[image: close-up of drive side of bottom bracket]
[image: overall view of frame from non-drive side]
[image: view from underneath the bottom bracket]
[image: bottom view of the chainstays]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I don't think I've ever seen a frame that looked more homemade than that.  Are you sure it _has_ a brand?

Comment: The tube shapes are quite distinctive. Someone into the downhill scene in the 2000s would probably recognise it straight away! Try the forum on RetroBike.co.uk

Comment: If it is homemade it’s a pretty sturdy make that’s for sure. Thanks mate  I’ll post it over on there and see how i go